# Tracing web service calls

Tags: asp.net, web-services, httpwebrequest, webrequest, trace

Here is an outline of the technologies were are using for our project at work :

-ASP.NET MVC 4
-Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2010
-Entity Framework Version 4
-Umbraco 6.1.6

We are invoking Web Services API belonging to a Third-party Company.

In order to ensure debugging and troubleshooting are made easier, we want our application to create a details log trace of all calls to the Third-party Web Service API.
I vaguely recall from my previous place of work that there was a way to setup some kind of configuration in ASP.NET web.config that would log trace all calls to Web Services API into a text file.

What configuration changes do I need to make?

Comment: We don't need detailed instructions on how you want us to use Stack Overflow - especially not if you make that the entirety of your question title. We (most of us, anyway) know how to answer questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to reconfigure some system specific data in the following xml, but just place it in your ASP.NET Web.config, and it should create log files showing how your application invokes/calls Web Services

```
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"  type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider,System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="1">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
  </compiler>
</compilers>
</system.codedom>

  <system.diagnostics>

<trace autoflush="true" />

<sources>
  <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="1024">
    <listeners>
      <add name="MyTraceFile"/>
      <add name="MyConsole"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>

<sharedListeners>
  <!-- initializeData="System.Net.trace.log" -->
  <!-- type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" -->
  <!--  type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" -->
  <add
    name="MyTraceFile"
     type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"  

    initializeData="D:\Log\Trace.log"
    />
    <add name="MyConsole" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
</sharedListeners>

<switches>
  <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
  <!--            <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />-->
</switches>

  </system.diagnostics>
```